# Why is my java program skipping user string input?

Tags: java, string, input, java.util.scanner

```
  static boolean check(double money)
  {
    String scont, yes = "yes", no = "no";
    boolean bcont;
    if (money == 0) {
      System.out.println("You are broke and can no longer play.");
      bcont = false;
      return bcont;
    }
    System.out.println("You have " + form.format(money) + " left.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue playing? (Yes or no?)");
    scont = in.nextLine();
    if (scont.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
      bcont = true;
      return bcont;
    }
    else if (scont.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
      bcont = false;
      return bcont;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Invalid answer.");
      bcont = check(money);
      return bcont;
    }
  }
```

This is, obviously, only a singular function in my program. When it gets to `scont = in.nextLine();` it skips the user input and breaks the loop the function is in, in the main function.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write `else if (scont.equalsIgnoreCase(no) == false) {` ?

Comment: I suspect the problem might be outside of this particular method.  In particular, you may be fetching a number from the `Scanner`, but not fetching the new line following it.  Can you post all of your code please, so we can see if this is the problem?

Comment: A side note: `equalsIgnoresCase()` returns a boolean. You don't need to do a comparison on booleans (e.g `equalsIgnoresCase() == true` can just be shortened to `equalsIgnoresCase()`. If you want the conditional block to execute then the method returns `false`, you can use the `!` (not) operator.

Comment: Thanks Java Devil. That sounds like it might be the problem. I will check it out and let you know.

Comment: It seems that was the issue. Now I have another issue. It will skip the user input once. Then, it will go to the else statement, call itself, and then it will allow for user input. This does not make sense to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you're reading the money value from the `Scanner` which is not consuming the newline characters. In that case add `in.nextLine()` to consume this character

```
double money = in.nextDouble();
in.nextLine(); // add
boolean result = check(money);
```

(Of course `BigDecimal` is the preferred datatype for monetary amounts)

Comment: @Patriot524 yes I know :)

Comment: Oops sorry dumb comment.... i feel stupid....  ='(

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- You should always use `.equals()` in place of `==` for String
  comparison in Java
- But, this is a moot point because `equalsIgnoreCase()` returns a boolean value anyway; you don't need to perform boolean evaluations in your conditionals
- I suspect you may be incorrectly making use of the `Scanner` class, as observed by @David Wallace

It might pay to check your usage of the `Scanner` class. You can identify whether or not this is the root of your problem by simply using a `BufferedReader` to temporarily receive the user input.

e.g.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
...
scont = br.readLine();
```

Comment: I attempted using `System.readline()` however no such method exists according to the compiler. Perhaps a class name? I tried using `System.in.readline()` however that did not exist either, however `System.in` does.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. See my edited answer.